# Simple Search "You are not permitted to use the search engine." if I am not logged in

Tags: search, simple-search

I have a simple search form installed on EE3, and I am only allowed to use the site search if I am logged in to the control panel. Is there a permissions setting I am missing somewhere? I don't have any URLs blacklisted.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Members › Member Groups ›  Guests ›  Access search utility.

Should solve your problem